# Partitoning to install Ubuntu but already have 4 main partitions

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I want to install Ubuntu alongside of Windows, but there's a 4 primary partitions limit.
So there's:

BIOS_RVY (10GB)

System (100MB) (Windows)

(C:) Windows

(D:) Data

I'm not sure what to do in this situation. This is my girlfriend's laptop and she doesn't want to remove MSI's pre-installed recovery partition, even though I'm pretty sure she's never used it. What is it exactly?
Also, does Grub render Windows's "System" partition redundant?

Comment: I don't have an HP_Tools partition to delete like the poster from that thread.

Comment: The method is the same, you have to decide what partition to nuke.

Comment: Yes I realize that. What I'm asking in the question is if anyone knows what exactly the recovery partition is and is it needed? I googled it and didn't find any answers. Also is the Windows "System" partition needed.

Comment: `BIOS_RVY` seems like a RecoVerY partition. If you want you can mirror it to a CD/USB/image disk and then nuke it.

Comment: Grub is a boot loader, has nothing to do with the Windows SYSTEM partition

Comment: Note that the 4-partition limit applies only to MBR disks. The vast majority of systems that shipped with Windows 8, and some that shipped with Windows 7, use the newer GPT system, which doesn't suffer from this limit.